# Can you please tell why doesn't this C program works as expected?

Tags: c, io, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int t,k,n,i;
    int height[20000];
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d%d",&k,&n);
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) scanf("%d",&height[i]);
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d\n",height[i]);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

For input:
 1 
 3 1
2 5 4
 I am expecting an output of 
 2
5
4
but I am getting an output of 
 2 
 please help

Comment: It's not clear what environment you're programming in, but at the very least you could use some `printf` for simple debug (output what you just read in with `scanf` to see if it's what you expect).

Comment: If t and n are equal to 1 means the loop will executed only once.

Comment: use the --> operator like so: while(t --> 0)

Comment: @chux ah okay, didn't realize (I never use `scanf` anyway)

Answer (score 2):

In your input you set `t` to 1, `k` to 3 and **`n` to 1**. So your `for`s perform only one loop afterwards. '5' and '4' are not even scanned from the input.

Answer (score 0):

Read your code more carefully.
After Your input:

```
t= 1
k= 3
n= 1
```

then You make loop on n = 1 , so it reads one integer:

```
height[0] = 2
```

5 and 4 are omitted,

then it prints 2.

k is not used...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int t,k,n,i;
    int height[20000];
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&k,&n);
        printf("value of k is %d\nvalue of n is %d\n",k,n);
```

**AS PER YOUR INPUT N IS 1 HERE**

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) 
   scanf("%d",&height[i]);
```

***`**i<n condition is wrong here it wont let more than 1 value to get scanned for n=1**`***

```
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++) 
       printf("%d\n",height[i]);
}
            return 0;
}
```

Comment: so basically change the value of n according to the no of values you wish to scan.

Answer (score 0):

change you code like this :

```
while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d%d",&k,&n);
        for(i = 0; i < k; i++) scanf("%d",&height[i]);
        for(i = 0; i < k; i++) printf("%d\n",height[i]);
    }
```

and it will work as your expected.
By the way , why you only use n but get k and n both? It is no sense.